# Scheduler runInBackground not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I am working on a project where need to run CRON every hour and fetching lots of latest data for each time I run CRON and there are multiple user.

The CRON is taking time to complete for each user, so I am trying to run the CRON on background so that will not affect other crons too.

```
$users = User::where("connected", 1)->where("role_id", 2)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $schedule->command('fetch:product ' . $user->id)->cron('* */4 * * *');
    $schedule->command('fetch:report ' . $user->id)->hourly()->runInBackground();
}
```

From the above example first CRON is working but another one is not working because I have added `->runInBackground()` function so that it work in background and I have enabled the log but log in showing only of first CRON not second CRON.

Code is currently on Windows Server later will be moved to Linux.

Comment: i have same issue (windows 10)